# pandas.to_xml() with nested xml blocks

Tags: python, pandas, xml, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I create table in PostgreSQL and insert to table nested XML(xml_part column):

```sql
CREATE TABLE text_xml (
    id numeric,
    xml_part XML
);


insert into text_xml
values (1, '<note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Dont forget me this weekend!</body></note>');

insert into text_xml
values (2, '<note><to>Tove</to><from>Alex</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Dont forget me this weekend!</body></note>');
```

Further, I try to read the table in Python with sqlalchemy and pandas:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pds

# Create an engine instance
alchemyEngine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://<credentials>', pool_recycle=3600)

# Connect to PostgreSQL server
dbConnection = alchemyEngine.connect()

# Read data from PostgreSQL database table and load into a DataFrame instance
dataFrame = pds.read_sql("select * from text_xml", dbConnection)

print(dataFrame.to_xml(index=False))
```

and I got in print:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<data>
  <row>
    <id>2.0</id>
    <xml_part>&lt;note&gt;&lt;to&gt;Tove&lt;/to&gt;&lt;from&gt;Alex&lt;/from&gt;&lt;heading&gt;Reminder&lt;/heading&gt;&lt;body&gt;Dont forget me this weekend!&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/note&gt;</xml_part>
  </row>
  <row>
    <id>1.0</id>
    <xml_part>&lt;note&gt;&lt;to&gt;Tove&lt;/to&gt;&lt;from&gt;Jani&lt;/from&gt;&lt;heading&gt;Reminder&lt;/heading&gt;&lt;body&gt;Dont forget me this weekend!&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/note&gt;</xml_part>
  </row>
</data>
```

HTML symbols `&lt; and &gt;` ruin my result. I would like to receive without HTML characters like this:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<data>
  <row>
    <id>2.0</id>
    <xml_part><note><to>Tove</to><from>Alex</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Dont forget me this weekend!</body></note></xml_part>
  </row>
  <row>
    <id>1.0</id>
    <xml_part><note><to>Tove</to><from>Alex</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Dont forget me this weekend!</body></note></xml_part>
  </row>
</data>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There are several layers of problem here. Putting XML raw into a relational database is almost never a good idea - better to make a true, normalized table with columns for `to`, `from`, `heading`, `body`.

Comment: Don't embed sensitive database credentials in your code.

Comment: `&lt;` is called an [entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SGML_entity)